# How to change WordPress menu with image bullets?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on WordPress theme menu

[Current WP menu]

```
    <ul>
        <li><a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>">Home</a></li>
        <?php wp_list_pages('title_li'); ?>
    </ul>
```

Generates Output:

```
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Book Online</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Prices</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
```

What changes I can do in my code to generate following output:

```
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/bullet.png" width="15" height="9" />Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/bullet.png" width="15" height="9" />Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/bullet.png" width="15" height="9" />Book Online</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/bullet.png" width="15" height="9" />Prices</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/bullet.png" width="15" height="9" />Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

use some thing like

```
<?php
                    $args = array(
        'title_li'     => __('Pages'),

    'link_before'   => '<img src="'.get_bloginfo('template_url').'/images/bullet.png" width="15" height="9" />'

);
                    wp_list_pages($args); ?>
```

hope this works for you

Comment: Yes , it works well ! , Do it will get pages links only? I want links from 'Main Menu'.

Comment: this is not the right way of geting the menu you have to use wp_nav_menu() function for wordpress.read the link http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu

Answer (score 0):

Apply this bullet image in background of a tag through css.this will easier then putting it in li